# knockoutjs and isotope adding new item causing first element to jump around

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-isotope, knockout-3.0

I am using knockoutjs and isotope masonary layout, with the custom binding based on the code **[blog link here](http://zubinraj.com/blog/2013/10/21/implementing-isotope-with-knockout-js/)** and shown below:

View:

```
<div id="container" class="isotope" data-bind="foreach: bills">
    <div class="item" data-bind="isotope: {container: '#container', itemSelector: '.item'}, style: {height: RandomHeight() + 'px'}">
        <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
        <p>Votes: <span data-bind="text: votes"></span><p>
        <p data-bind="text: desc"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And ViewModel and custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.isotope = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.init = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        console.log("init...");
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        var $container = $(value.container);

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: value.itemSelector,
            masonry: {
              columnWidth: 100
            }
        });
    };

    self.update = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $el = $(element);
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        console.log("updating..." + value);
        var $container = $(value.container);
        $container.isotope('appended', $el);
    };

    return {
        init: self.init,
        update: self.update
    }
}();
```

The issue is when I add a new item and append it to the list, the first item jumps from left to right. The items at the top should remain statically positioned, only the items at the bottom should shuffle around, an example screenshot of this happening (mid-jump_ is at the bottom of the post.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong please?

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/zoohcveh/4/

[image: brick jump]

Comment: how you want it....can you tell me what output you want?

Comment: Hi Devendra, if you click the Add button a number of times you will see the first item jumping from left to right whereas it should remain statically positioned... the only movement should be at the end of the grid where the last brick is added

Comment: What is the browser you are using? It is working fine in Firefox for me. Or I didn't undestrand the problem.

Comment: The first element jumps around in IE and Chrome, have posted a screengrab of the issue.

Comment: So is the problem that there should be two elements on the first line or that you want only 1 element but for it to stay still?

Comment: Better example added, the masonry grid will allow as many items as the width allows, so it may be 2, 3, 4 or more bricks wide.  It is always the first brick that jumps, whereas the first row should always be full.. best way to think about it is like a brick wall where new bricks are added on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your isotope binding is on an `item`, if you read the log carefully, **isotope does another init every time you add new items**. This will definitely cause trouble.

The right way is to use isotope binding on the top level container, only init it once.
But we also need to keep (aka extend) the behaviour of `foreach` binding.

To fire the animation of `isotope` after new item was added, you need to use `foreach`'s `afterAdd` callback. Read more here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

http://jsfiddle.net/zoohcveh/27/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" class="isotope" data-bind="isotope: bills, isotopeOptions: {
                itemSelector: '.item',
                masonry: {
                  columnWidth: 182
                }
            }">
    <div class="item" data-bind="style: {height: RandomHeight() + 'px'}">
        <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
        <p>Votes: <span data-bind="text: votes"></span></p>
        <p data-bind="text: desc"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// use a factory method since most code of 'init' and 'update' are shared.
function initOrUpdate(method) {
    return function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        function isotopeAppend(ele) {
            // runs isotope animation
            console.log('nodeType ' + ele.nodeType);
            // nodeType 3 is Text (the empty space before and after div.item)
            // nodeType 1 is element
            if (ele.nodeType === 1) { // Element type
              console.log("appended isotope");
              $(element).isotope('appended', ele).isotope('layout');
            }
        }

        function attachCallback(valueAccessor) {
            return function() {
                return {
                    data: valueAccessor(),
                    afterAdd: isotopeAppend,
                };
            };
        }

        // extend foreach binding
        ko.bindingHandlers.foreach[method](element,
            attachCallback(valueAccessor), // attach 'afterAdd' callback
            allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);

        if (method === 'init') {
            console.log('init...');
            var options = allBindings.get('isotopeOptions') || {};
            console.log("options " + JSON.stringify(options));
            $(element).isotope(options);

            ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
                $(element).isotope("destroy");
            });
        } else {
            console.log("updating...");
        }
    }
}

ko.bindingHandlers.isotope = {
    init: initOrUpdate('init'),
    update: initOrUpdate('update')
};
```

**UPDATE**

To be good citizen, add dispose callback for `$(element).isotope("destroy");`.

Comment: Many thanks this is perfect, trying to understand the code can you please expand on ko.bindingHandlers.foreach[method]() is this an array of functions and how does it work? I will award the bounty now :)

Comment: `obj["init"]` is same as `obj.init`. It is just a flexible way to get a property out of javascript object. Remember every js object is a hash.

Comment: Updated answer for dispose callback.

Comment: played isotope for a while, it's not easy to get it work with knockout. Knockout wants to control view based on model, but isotope has no data layer, all its functions are based on DOM. I have not found a clean way to support isotope filters (isotope filter is based on css class, not data).

Comment: When I am adding 50 elements at a time, the isotope update is being called 3 times as many (150 times) and causing some slow down... http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/e6oLkxwc/12/ any idea why this is? Can we store a local copy of each item that gets added then after a certain delay of no more items being added then fire off a single batch update to help increase performance?

Comment: I didn't expect this. Knockout fires afterAdd 3 times for 3 different nodes, one "Text" node (empty space before div), one "div" node, and another "Text" node (empty space after div). This is defined in DOM standard, every empty space is a node in DOM structure. The solution is to check `nodeType` before running isotope appended. Updated answer.

Comment: I have added batch updates, with this all performance issues are resolved as far as i can tell - http://jsfiddle.net/g18c/e6oLkxwc/34/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/zombiesplat/zoohcveh/17/ Here is a working version of what I answered below.

The problem appears to be some kind of compatibility issue with isotope v2 and knockout.  My fix came from finding this example http://zubinraj.com/demo/isotope-knockout/isotope-knockout-binding.htm and converting your code to use knockout v1.5

HTML

```
<div>
    <button data-bind="click: addNew">Add New</button>
</div>

<div id="container" class="isotope" data-bind="foreach: bills">
    <div class="item" data-bind="isotope: {container: '#container', itemSelector: '.item'}, style: {height: RandomHeight() + 'px'}">
        <h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>
        <p>Votes: <span data-bind="text: votes"></span><p>
        <p data-bind="text: desc"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* ---- .item ---- */

.item {
  float: left;
  width: 380px;
  background: #0D8;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.7);
}


/* Begin Required Isotope Styles - see http://isotope.metafizzy.co for more info */
 .isotope-item {
    z-index: 2;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
 .isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -moz-transition-property: height, width;
    -ms-transition-property: height, width;
    -o-transition-property: height, width;
    transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity;
    -ms-transition-property: -ms-transform, opacity;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform, opacity;
    transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
 .isotope.no-transition, .isotope.no-transition .isotope-item, .isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0s;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

Javascript on Dom Ready

```
var $container = $("#container");
var data = [
    {
        title: "Test 1",
        desc: "Some description text goes here",
        votes: 1000,
        category: "catA",
    },
    {
        title: "Test 2",
        desc: "Some description text goes here",
        votes: 2000,
        category: "catB",
    },
    {
        title: "Test 3",
        desc: "Some description text goes here",
        votes: 100,
        category: "catC",
    }
];

function Bill(title, desc, votes, category)
{
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable(title);
    self.desc = ko.observable(desc);
    self.votes = ko.observable(votes);
    self.category = ko.observable(category);
    self.RandomHeight = ko.observable(Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 400);
    console.log("Added new bill");
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.bills = ko.observableArray();

    self.count = 1;

    self.search = function() {
        self.bills.removeAll();
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        {
            var bill = new Bill(
                data[i].title,
                data[i].desc,
                data[i].votes,
                data[i].category
            );
            self.bills.push(bill);
        }
    };

    self.addNew = function() {
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        {
            var bill = new Bill(
                self.count,
                data[i].desc,
                data[i].votes,
                data[i].category
            );
            self.bills.push(bill);
            self.count++;
        }
    };
};

ko.bindingHandlers.isotope = {
    init : function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

    },  
    update : function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $el = $(element);
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        console.log("updating..." + value);
        var $container = $(value.container);
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: value.itemSelector,
            masonry: {
              columnWidth: 100
            }
        });
        $container.isotope('appended', $el);
    }

};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: I was able to replicate the problem with the example at zubinraj.com by using isotope v2 on his exact same code.

Comment: interesting, any idea why? been pulling my hair out thinking was my code

Comment: I have no idea why honestly. what I did notice was that you could replicate with a simple resize of the container, and that isotope left room for 2 elements at the beginning no matter what I did.